# Is Asp.Net MVC a suitable solution for an enterprise project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are preparing to develop an enterprise Human Resources Project using ASP.NET and our team is interested in using MVC instead of WebForms but we are a bit worried about this.

We are not sure that this is a suitable solution for an Enterprise project.

Comment: Why is your team interested in using MVC? Can you elaborate so we can determine if they're making correct assumptions?

Comment: We are using a lot of javascript and ajax functionality that can not be developed easily using WebForms and updatepanels. Also Ajax Control Toolkit has poor performance and so on...

Comment: @Nima Its good question :) tnx +1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your developers have not yet worked on any solutions using a Model-View-Controller concept, they will find that the ASP.Net MVC Framework will have **quite a bit of a steep learning curve**.

This is because it's not built on the usual code behind and .aspx physical pages that you normally use in a Web-Forms application, but everything is separated accordingly into a View, a Controller and a Model.

**If the deadline for your application is a strict one, I do not suggest that you build it with the MVC Framework, but rather stick with what the developers already know, being Web-Form based applications.**

But, if the management is willing to give time to your developers to learn about the 'new' (*more like, different rather than new*) concept and get comfortable with it, then Yes, by all means, go for it and develop it using the MVC Framework.

Answer (score 4):

I made the switch from WebForms shortly after the preview releases started coming out and have been using the MVC framework ever since. It makes building and deploying work so much easier and more importantly, I think it makes for better teamwork.

Two people can simultaneously work on the same "page" in MVC while in WebForms working two people to a page ends up being much more of a challenge. This works great for my team because my designer can lock down the page layout at the same time I am working on the logic for the view.

It'll take a little bit of time to get used to, but once you get the mechanics of it down you'll find that it really expands capabilities of your web work very nicely.

EDIT - One of my team members reminded me that while we use MVC as the framework, we are still barely using a tenth of what the project offers and we are still getting amazing mileage out of it. And I think somebody else mentioned it, but it deserves repeating... stackoverflow is developed on ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 3):

This june I chose WebForms over MVC since MVC wasn't "mature" yet.

Can't tell you how sorry I am now.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC is just a different model than classic ASP.NET, an extension if you will.

From [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/AnArchitecturalViewOfTheASPNETMVCFramework.aspx):

> The ASP.NET MVC Framework is
>   essentially the Microsoft's attempt to
>   create an ASP.NET programming
>   environment centered around the MVC
>   pattern. For the time being the MVC Framework should
>   be considered an alternative to Web
>   Forms. To some extent, the MVC
>   Framework and Web Forms have in common
>   more or less what cars and motorcycles
>   share. Both can take you somewhere
>   else, but with different speed,
>   comfort, sense of freedom, size of the
>   trunk.

stackoverflow for example is built on it and works great.

More info here: [Should I migrate to ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067)

Even more info: http://www.coderjournal.com/2008/12/introducing-aspnet-mvc-part-2-aspnet-mvc-vs-webforms/

Answer (score 0):

Technically, I see no issue with MVC, but one: It's beta, and some stuff is still going to change. Nothing groundbreaking like during the previews, but a little overview of what will change between the current Beta and the upcoming Release Candidate is available [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/12/19/asp-net-mvc-design-gallery-and-upcoming-view-improvements-with-the-asp-net-mvc-release-candidate.aspx).

Legally, it's a different thing. While Microsoft explicitely allows live deployment, I am not sure if they are liable yet for any damages due to bugs, since it's beta. I know, Legal Action because of Bugs sounds silly, but some Management teams want to have a bullet proof "This software works, and if not, we pay you"-license, which is not the case with MVC yet.