# Does someone have real project experience using asp.net mvc implement complicated web UI app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my past projects I've been using webform to implement windows form style complicated backend admin page by using asp.net webform.

Just wondering by using asp.net mvc, can it make this kind of complicated UI page much easier?

Comment: I thought, from the title, that I understood what you were asking. However, your question is a bit confusing. Can you try to clarify that or ask it differently?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712220/whats-your-choice-for-your-next-asp-net-project-webforms-or-mvc

Comment: I just want to compare webform and mvc the pro and con in terms of complicated UI page, for example: a page contains 3 level nested gridview controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This highly depends on what UI you need. For me, it wouldn't be easy without jQuery... but with jQuery it's very convenient.

For example of possible nesting, my app has cart that contains Accordion for customers, with each pane containing custom tabs with sliding animations for orders, with each order containing table of items, where each item can be expanded to show included products details (not to mention context menus to change customers, on-the-fly discounts changing with notification tooltips, popups to show product details, and so on). All this on single page. And I still find it very easy to manage, because all the functionality is well split across MVC controllers and views.

As for "admin part", I use two-level nesting (with second level on another page, but I just don't want to go deep into jqGrid), and it's 5 minutes to setup a new admin page using AutoMapper, custom attributes, and some [custom code](http://sprokhorenko.blogspot.com/2010/01/jqgrid-mvc-new-version-sources.html). Got new entity (e.g. SomeProduct)? 5 minutes and new admin page with grid, custom editing controls and formats is done. With MVC.

But if you need traditional "data grid" approach, chances that ASP.NET will do better. Or maybe jqGrid (or third-party grids like Telerik) will help you, because they have subgrids and all this stuff. I would say, if you don't like Domain-Driven Design, if your application is not object/entity driven, but highly based on raw data tables, then MVC might be not what you need. But I may be wrong because I never worked with such applications. All other apps, I'd prefer MVC.

Comment: Thanks queen3, my app is pure DDD app, i am using subsonic as my ORM. I was using Bubbling Events quite a lot in webform app. It is make UI related to code quite complicated. It seems by using jQuery can make it easier. I will try to use it.