# Moving from WebForms to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i know ASP.NET and i would like to learn and make a new project in ASP.NET MVC.
Is it easy to move from asp.net to asp.net mvc? Will the knowledge i have so far be helpful? 
Im asking because i will have only few days to learn asp.net mvc and i want to know whether it's possible...

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067/should-i-migrate-to-asp-net-mvc) questions (and its answers) very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it easy to move from asp.net to
>   asp.net mvc?

My answer to this would be a question back to you.  **Do you understand HTTP?**  **Is web forms sort of magical to you, or do you have a firm grasp of what the abstraction is doing?**

The reason I ask is that MVC sort of strips away a lot of the "magic" that web forms gives you in terms of treating a stateless protocol as actually having state.  I tend to think of out of the box web forms development closer to classic windows forms development then normal web development.  There are good and bad things about that.

What MVC is doing is bringing closer to what is actually happening in HTTP and in the end giving you more control and power over that.  What you won't find in MVC is slew of drag and drop datagrid type controls, but it will make it easier to write AJAX heavy sites with common javascript libraries and clean html, as well as enable you to more easily write testable code.

> Will the knowledge i have so far be helpful?

Without knowing what your "knowledge" is, it is hard to say.  **Obviously c# and vb are the same it's not like its a new language.**
It really comes down to what type of web developer you were in asp.net forms.  If you found yourself annoyed at how IDs were generated and how the html output of controls was horrible and that the framework was making it hard to do what you want then you should be fine.

If you were like I stated before, more of a drag and drop type of web forms person than MVC might be a bit challenging, but I would say **its a good challenge and something that will ultimately make you a better web developer**.

> The only way you'll really know is if you try... There are tons of [resources out there to get you started.](http://www.asp.net/mvc/)

Hope that helps.  Don't be afraid to ask questions on here as you go, there are tons of MVC devs on this site.

Comment: thanks for the answer. 
What do you mean by understanding HTTP. I don't know how exactly does this protocol works :( 
Generally i started with PHP writing some simple cms, online shop etc. and as far as i remember ASP.NET was a little bit magic at the beginning. But then i liked it as i like WindowsForms.. 

anyway, i think i will give it a try, the only thing i can lose is time ;)

Comment: What I mean by understanding HTTP is really just do you understand how the web works.  What is a GET vs POST. What do status codes mean.  That it's stateless, but asp.net does things to make it have state. How caching works in browsers.  All of these things are exposed to you in a more obvious way in MVC so its good to know.

Comment: yes, of course i know these things ;) 
thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If you've ever used technologies like ASP classic, Coldfusion, PHP, etc. where you intersperse regular markup with server-side logic, then you will be able to pick up the "view" syntax pretty easily.  The controllers are pretty simple to grasp once you get the hang of it, and the model shouldn't have to change from what you are used to.  The hardest part for me to grasp when first learning ASP.NET MVC was the routing.

Like anything else, it will take some effort before you learn the "right" ways to do certain things, and you will initially be a bit less productive in the new technology.  But in the end it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I felt that ASP.NET MVC was far easier to learn than ASP.NET WebForms.

Run through the NerdDinner tutorial.  It should take you about half-a-day.  I think you'll find the simplicity refreshing.

Comment: Although it doesn't replace a thorough understanding of how ASP.NET works.