# Is ASP.NET MVC vulnerable to the oracle padding attack?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

Is ASP.NET MVC 2 vulnerable to the [oracle padding attack](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/18/important-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx)?  If so, what workaround should be implemented?  The instructions on Scott Gu's blog appear to only be for Webforms.

I tried this:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="/Home/ErrorPage" />
```

however, http://www.example.com/PageThatDoesNotExist still returns a standard 404 error page.

*EDIT*: I see that Scott Gu posted in the comments under his blog post that MVC is vulnerable, but it's still not clear to me exactly how to implement the workaround.

Comment: I am very curious about this as well.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749083/oracle-padding-exploit-how-does-it-download-the-web-config

Comment: Just updated my question as Scott posted an FAQ here - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/20/frequently-asked-questions-about-the-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720720/how-serious-is-this-new-asp-net-security-vulnerability-and-how-can-i-workaround-i this covers it too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yes](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/18/important-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx#7614901Scott) - linkage to the comment by Scott Guthrie.

> Saturday, September 18, 2010 9:00 PM by ScottGu
>
> @Vijay,
>
> > Will the ASP.NET MVC too get affected?
>
> Yes - all versions of ASP.NET are affected, including ASP.NET MVC.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Scott

I see that you've seen the comment, but if you run the vbs script on your server, it should tell you if it's still a problem.

**Edit:** Also, Scott has discussed FAQs in a new post [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/20/frequently-asked-questions-about-the-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx).

Comment: I can't run the script, as I deploy on Azure.  Also, the script doesn't appear to work with the Casini web server (the one used by VS).  Thanks for your thoughts though.

Answer (score 2):

Under your default route you could/should add this for starters

```
routes.MapRoute("Catch All", "{*path}", new { controller = "Home", action = "ErrorPage" });
```

**Edit 2**

the problem lies in the part `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` without this, it works.

using the route though will fix 1 part of the problem, where the path cant be found (404)

the next part, like existing paths with bad ID's or other data, could be fixed with

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Home/ErrorPage" />
```

what exactly does `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` do?

**Edit: what it does.**

redirectMode

- ResponseRedirect: Specifies that the
  URL to direct the browser to must be
  different from the original Web
  request URL.
- ResponseRewrite:
  Specifies that the URL to direct the
  browser to must be the original Web
  request URL.

It only matters for .NET 3.5 SP1 and .NET 4.0.

**Edit 101:**

For redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" the ASP.NET calls Server.Execute(...) internally, which does not work with MVC routes, so for MVC this only works with a static HTML file.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/error.htm" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" />
```

works.

Comment: The only difference between the OP code sample and yours is that yours has `.aspx` on the end of the `defaultRedirect` attribute, which isn't required in .NET MVC.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx explains what redirectMode does.

Answer (score 2):

This question is included in Scott Gu's [Frequently Asked Questions about the ASP.NET Security Vulnerability](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/20/frequently-asked-questions-about-the-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx):

> **Does this affect both ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC?**
>
> Yes – the publicly disclosed exploit can be used against all types of ASP.NET Applications (including both Web Forms and MVC).

Answer (score 2):

I posted my full take on this (after extra research) on [my blog](http://eglasius.blogspot.com/2010/09/aspnet-padding-oracle-impact-on-aspnet.html).

**Update note: moved the link to a post specific to asp.net MVC**

---

I strongly believe the issue with the 404s is related to WebResources and ScriptResources (which can disable for asp.net MVC btw), as those probably give 404s when the corresponding resource isn't found (which would be the normal response to an valid padding that gives an invalid resource path/name).

Other error codes & messages could be an issue for other asp.net features, but ending with a 404 only because you hit an url non related to any special handler shouldn't be causing the issue.

Also note what I mentioned in this answer:
[How serious is this new ASP.NET security vulnerability and how can I workaround it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720720/how-serious-is-this-new-asp-net-security-vulnerability-and-how-can-i-workaround-i/3766865#3766865)

> if the app is asp.net MVC we don't really need webresources.axd and/or scriptresources.axd, so those can be turned off. We also don't use viewstate.
>
> asp.net membership provider 'caches' roles in cookies, turn that off.
>
> The auth cookie is signed, and from the info in the paper they shouldn't be able to generate a signed cookie if they don't get to the actual keys (as they did in the video before forging the auth cookie).
>
> As Aristos mentioned, for the session id in the cookie, that's random for the user session, so it'd have to be sniffed from an user with the target security level and cracked while that session is active. Even then if you are relying in authentication to assign/authorize the user operations, then the impact would be minimal / it'd depend a lot in what Session is used for in that app.

Answer (score 1):

A patch for this bug has been released on Windows Update.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/30/asp-net-security-fix-now-on-windows-update.aspx

Comment: Doesn't mention ASP.NET MVC at all.

Comment: The vulnerability is in ASP.NET; MVC is only vulnerable because ASP.NET is. This patch fixes the root problem.

Comment: Yeah, but there are several questions here about the padding oracle attack. This one is about its specific relevance to ASP.NET MVC. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a route/controller action setup to return an error page for the `/Home/ErrorPage` route?

Comment: Yes, I can definitely see `http://www.example.com/Home/ErrorPage` directly, but that page isn't called from customErrors.

Comment: Do you just see the standard browser 404 when you put in a url that doesn't go to any page?

Comment: yes, I just see a standard 404 error.  My understanding is that all errors should display /Home/ErrorPage instead.

Comment: @Needing Anything as long as they don't display anything based predictably on the input.