# Oracle padding security related query

Tags: security

I am still unable to figure out the following which are related to Oracle padding security issue. The no. 1 point is in general which I wanted to know the easy way to change the Machine key. The no. 2 point is related to Security issue.

1. If I change the machine key then how easily I can change the user passwords stored in the DB. User passwords are also encrypted with same machine key. Changing the key will make passwords to become invalid. Please correct me if I am mistaken.
2. In webresource.axd?d=..., What is the data type stored in 'd' parameter. How it will allow to download any arbitrary file. I know only that it can allow embedded resources to download. But can someone show an example to download web.config file using webresource.axd. Everybody talks that web.config can be downloaded but I did not find an example of doing that.

I will be glad to know if someone can answer with simple example. Please do not point me to ScotGu blog and after reading his blog and recommendation I do not want to visit his blog again and am surprised to know how he is leading asp.net team.

Comment: Why are you surprised that he's leading the ASP.NET team? Insulting him isn't relevant to your question, and it's hardly appropriate on SO. Anyway, on his blog are links to the security fixes: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/28/asp-net-security-update-now-available.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer your questions from what [I have learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720720/how-serious-is-this-new-asp-net-security-vulnerability-and-how-can-i-workaround-i) about the issue so far.

1. User passwords in the DB are **not at all** related to the machine key of the app. The ASP.NET worker process by default generates a new machine key every time your app is restarted.
   (Thus, if the DB passwords were dependent on the machine key, they would become invalid in every few days.)
2. About downloading `Web.config`, we don't really know. Some people think that it is dependent on another security hole. If you use MVC (or WebForms without these), it is the safest if you **disable** the `.axd` requests. (Handle `*.axd` with `HttpForbiddenHandler`)

For example:

```
<httpHandlers>
    ...
    <remove verb="*" path="*.axd"/>
    <add validate="false" verb="*" path="*.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Or do the same in the `system.webServer` section if you are using IIS 7.

Comment: Yikes disabling axd's on a production asp.net site for most people generally is not an option, scriptmanager, 3rd party controls all routinely use WebResource.axd

Comment: @Chris - As I said, MVC doesn't use it, so it is a valid option for MVC pages.

Comment: 1. Since I use static Machine key in web.config and Asp.net membership provider will use that key to encrypt passwords if I store encrypted passwords in DB. Hence changing the Machine key is not as easy as it looks. U cannot encrypt passwords if u use autogenerated key.

Comment: 2. I cannot disable *.axd due to my project design. I need webresource.axd functionality. I am surprised that people talk about that web.config can be downloaded with webresource.axd. I am not asking to disable *.axd but asking how it will download web.config

Comment: @kumar, if it really works that way, use a custom MembershipProvider. 2. As I said, it relies on another vulnerability. :)

Comment: Just ignore my first part of question. I believe that I have to re-encrypt the pwds with new key but before that I have to collect pwd in unencrypted form. But for my second question, I don't understand why nobody is clearly telling me what the another vulnerability is which allows download of web.config file. Do anybody knows what another vulnerability is or u all just saying because others are saying it. Please clarify it. Once I know the vulnerability I can fix it myself rather than waiting for Microsoft to provide the patch.

Comment: Anyway, I figured out how it will allow download of web.config due to this vulnerability.

Comment: @kumar - really? Could you please share it with us?