# POET Attack on ASP.Net 4 [dnn]: Is there any way to block it?

Tags: asp.net, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How serious is this new ASP.NET security vulnerability and how can I workaround it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720720/how-serious-is-this-new-asp-net-security-vulnerability-and-how-can-i-workaround-i)

I just saw this video that shows a vulnerability in ASP.Net. Is there any way that we can block this kind of attacks?

[POET Attack on dnn](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yghiC_U2RaM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply [the security update which is going to be released today](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/27/asp-net-security-update-shipping-tuesday-sept-28th.aspx).

Alternatively, read [scottgu's FAQ about it](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/20/frequently-asked-questions-about-the-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx), including interim measures.