# Creating custom httphandler in web.config: Am I at risk of exposing a 'Padding Oracle' vulnerability?

Tags: asp.net, security, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

Considering the recent ASP.NET vulnerability, what should I look for in my httphandlers that would cause such a Padding Oracle vulnerability?

Asked in another way... what did MSFT do wrong and what did they fix in their handlers?

Answer (score 0):

I think the wronge is that they give "too much" informations about the error.

@Sri here analyze it very well
[How serious is this new ASP.NET security vulnerability and how can I workaround it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720720/how-serious-is-this-new-asp-net-security-vulnerability-and-how-can-i-workaround-i/3721473#3721473)

Comment: Which error?  How would I improperly implement the same thing in my code?

Comment: @MakerOfThings7 The error that you get when you give a false key to decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

There were 3 problems with WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd:

1. Working as a padding oracle. This is because these decrypted information send in the query string, and behaved differently when the decrypted string had invalid vs. valid padding - because it had been tampered with. The fix Microsoft made included using a HMAC to prevent the data from being tampered - this is checked before any padding check, so it doesn't expose padding information
2. Relying on normal encryption/decryption to receive a request for a resource/file. It isn't meant for that, a tamper proof mechanism is needed.
3. Allowing access of any kind of files, not only JavaScript files

Bottom line, don't allow more access than necessary and only if you really need encryption/decryption tamper proof it.

Back in the day I blogged about [how it related to getting different levels of access](http://eglasius.blogspot.com/2010/09/aspnet-padding-oracle-how-it-relates-to.html)