# Moving the App from ASP.NET to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, asp.net-mvc-2

I am having a aomplex and well-running application in ASP.NET that i have created about 2 years ago, now i want to create the same in ASP.NET MVC 2/3  to improve efficiency, because ASP.NET make use of ViewState a lot which eats lot of bytes. 
And I had also make use of ViewState a lot in that project. At a time on an estimation about 500 people give Quiz.

Now I want to mainly focus on client-side scripting using HTML5, CSS3, jQuery and ASP.NET MVC.
If you have used above technologies, than can you please suggest me that whether doing this is possible or not with increased efficiency in such project or application.

Please answer me your suggestion so that i can decide whether to move towards MVC or Silverlight.

Comment: Are you having problems with your application currently? If not, I wouldn't be inclined to rewrite it in MVC (if it isn't broke, don't fix it). If wanting to try out MVC, maybe start a new project in MVC? If I can't convince you, client side development does fit better with MVC than with web forms. I highly doubt however it's going to be any more efficient as both frameworks use the same underlying pipeline.

Comment: Be sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067/should-i-migrate-to-asp-net-mvc to be sure that you really want to migrate. If your application is running fine on Webforms, usually there is no need to migrate unless you're just bored and want something to do to mess with MVC

Comment: that app is having efficiency related problems which is due to use of excessive server side coding.Now I want to do exactly the same  for which MVC is developed by Microsoft.

Comment: If your problems are related to page size due to ViewState, simply turn it off..

Comment: @codymanix second that... MVC doesn't necessarily perform better than Webforms. You can write super inefficient code in both frameworks and moving a badly performing app doesn't just magically make it run faster.

Comment: Thanks to all for such good discussion , Yes I am now looking forward to rewrite the whole App from Scratch while ,i can use whole DataAccessLogic and partial Busines Logic of old App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, ASP.Net MVC + jQuery is very simple and powerful platform. We've done several sophisticated web-applications on that platform and that was very easy and interesting.

Comment: Fine for you that you wrote some ASP.NET MVC apps but the question was how hard is will be to migrate from ASP.NET to MVC.

Comment: It depends from your application. I think, the best approach is to rewrite whole app from scratch. If you have separated DataAccess/BusinessLogic layers, you can reuse them, but all UI and related code should be rewritten.

Comment: Yes i am now looking forward to rewrite the whole App from Scratch while ,i can use whole DataAccessLogic and partial Busines Logic of old App. Thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

Your time would be better spent tweaking your current app to reduce your reliance on ViewState.

Your existing app has numerous hours of bug fixes & user testing in it - 2 years worth in fact. A rewrite would throw all that away & introduce lots of new errors.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting an application with only 500 users to save on some viewstate bytes seems a very inefficient use of time.

Comment: Unless you are using the experience to learn MVC, being able to focus on learning the framework, having the domain logic already worked out.